# iOS Keyboard Fixed Local setting ill-respect to Phone County/Language setting

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

In Code I am Using Decimal type keyboard on a text field to enter decimal number. But when I change the phone country/language in phone settings from to Spain then my Decimal keyboard gets changed. The decimal (.) button converting to (,) and hence user unable to enter decimal point.

> I Want that my keyboard should not change with phone country language getting change. Keyboard local should always be English(US) "en_US". Please help.